# How to wrap a spiral into the outline of an object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to take the outline of an image such as this, and wrap a spiral into the object in photoshop or similar software for some classroom props I'm making. For example:  
[image]

And take the outline and wrap it into something like this:
[image]

The square is another example that might be simplification of the problem.

Thank you :)

Comment: Not sure I understand. What have you tired? For most things like this one would merely *daw* what you want. Not *everything* can be done via filters or automation.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator users know at least 2 ways. The first of them is to use Envelope Distortion

[image]

1. A spiral. It's drawn separately.
2. A closed path. It's a Bezier curve drawn by using the "Pen"
3. The closed path was used as "top object" when using Illustrators envelope distortion effect. It's Object > Envelope Distortion > Make with Top Object.

There's no parameters to adjust the distortion. The only way to get different result is to edit either the distorted shape or the envelope. It's fortunately easy because the effect is non-destructive. One can adjust the envelope with the direct selection tool and see the result in the fly. The envelope can be changed in the fly to mesh and that gives plenty of more control. But that's manual editing.

Another method is to map the planar shape onto a surface which is made by using one of 3D effects 1) Extrude & Bevel and 2) Revolve. Illustrator's 3D is limited and the user has poor control. The result is predictable when the surface is simple enough. An example:

[image]

4. A simple profile to be revolved. The curved edge has only 2 anchor points to keep the result simple enough. More anchors would make the mapping later very difficult because Illustrator splinters the surface to pieces which all need their own surface images.
5. A revolved "bell"
6. The same with mapped art. The spiral was dragged into the symbols collection and selected from there to be used as mapped art.
7. The result shown after removing the bell.

As you see, the width of the stroke doesn't stay constant, but varies and there's no way to control it. Illustrator's 3D was never developed to perfection, It has essentially been the same at least a decade. But that doesn't make it useless, it's still much more than nothing.

Photoshop users can distort their images by applying Warp or Puppet Warp to their images. It's a manual stretching and squeezing process, no automatic forcing into a predefined shape isn't provided. GIMP has also only manual distorting tools.

About the rectangular version:

Forcing a round spiral to straight perpendicular curve segments cannot be made by applying a few click effect in common graphics programs. You must draw it. But drawing it is easy - only click with the Pen in Illustrator.

[image]

Some graphics programs allow programmable mathematical transformations. Their possibilities are limited by the ability to write the needed transformations in the available programming language. I skip that subject.

**ADD:** Just to show that actual 3D programs have more control than Illustrator I insert an example. I revolved a simple bell like in Illustrator and wrapped a spiral on it. The rectangle is only a reference how wide planar area corresponds the whole 360 degrees around the bell:

[image]

The result can be exported as PDF to be used in Illustrator. The pieces are moved apart and a planar projection is made. The bell is taken along only as wireframe with no shading.

[image]

The used 3D program is Moi v4. It should be considered as "entry level". It's capabilities (and difficulty to get started, too) are far below what's available in Blender(free) or comparable commercial monsters.